PowerShell Get-WinEvent use FilterXml to select events with specific strings in the message property
I am trying to use powershell to look through event logs that have specific IP addresses in the message property. More specifically, I set auditpol to log Windows Firewall events to the Windows Security log and view them in Event Viewer. It would be faster if I could filter via PowerShell for the events with the IP I'm looking for. I've mainly been working in PowerShell ISE.
$PSVersionTable

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                         
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                         
PSVersion                      5.1.17763.5458     

Here is the auditpol commands I use to get the Windows Firewall events to the Security log:
#Check current status of firewall log settings
auditpol.exe /get /subcategory:'Filtering Platform Connection' | Select-string -Pattern 'Filtering Platform'
auditpol.exe /get /subcategory:'Filtering Platform Packet Drop' | Select-string -Pattern 'Filtering Platform'


#All of the above: Security 5156, 5158, 5157, and 5159:
auditpol.exe /set /subcategory:'Filtering Platform Connection' /success:enable /failure:enable

#Security Event ID 5152: The Windows Filtering Platform has blocked a packet:
auditpol.exe /set /subcategory:'Filtering Platform Packet Drop' /success:disable /failure:enable


#Check current status of firewall log settings again
auditpol.exe /get /subcategory:'Filtering Platform Connection' | Select-string -Pattern 'Filtering Platform'
auditpol.exe /get /subcategory:'Filtering Platform Packet Drop' | Select-string -Pattern 'Filtering Platform'

In event viewer, I filter for a specific time frame that my test takes place in, and for those event IDs, and I can use find to search for the IP I'm looking for. In this case, lets say the IP is 10.10.7.94. I can see this IP in Event Viewer by using Find. I go back to the filter and get the syntax from the XML tab as a beginning for my XML query. This is the syntax that got me closest to what I want (max events just to speed up testing):
$XmlQuery = @'
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">*[System[(EventID=5152 or  (EventID &gt;= 5156 and EventID &lt;= 5159) ) and TimeCreated[@SystemTime&gt;='2024-04-16T11:29:31.000Z' and @SystemTime&lt;='2024-04-16T11:30:48.999Z']]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
'@

[string]$SearchString = 10.10.7.94

Get-WinEvent -FilterXml $XmlQuery -MaxEvents 2 | Where-Object { $_.Message -like "*$SearchString*" } | select TimeCreated,ID,Message | Sort -Property TimeCreated | FL

This returns some events, but they do not contain the IP address I specified. An example of the message output I get returned is here:
Message     : The Windows Filtering Platform has permitted a connection.
              
              Application Information:
                Process ID:     3752
                Application Name:   \device\harddiskvolume4\windows\system32\dns.exe
              
              Network Information:
                Direction:      Inbound
                Source Address:     10.10.7.60
                Source Port:        40536
                Destination Address:    10.10.7.3
                Destination Port:       53
                Protocol:       17
              
              Filter Information:
                Filter Run-Time ID: 674097
                Layer Name:     Receive/Accept
                Layer Run-Time ID:  44

Variations I've tried:
Not using the string casting (this doesn't return results at all)
Single and double quotes around the IP address in the variable (this doesn't return results at all)
Not using a variable and putting the IP directly in the where filter (this doesn't return results at all)
Use the "contains" operator instead of "like" (this doesn't return results at all)
What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
